# What is the Elpy "autodoc" module and how do I enable it?

Tags: elpy

In the documentation for Elpy 1.35, near the part about `elpy-doc`, there is a statment to the effect of

> If the autodoc module is enabled (not by default) ...

**What is the autodoc module, and how does one enable it?** I cannot find more information about it in the Elpy documentation, and even grep'ing through the Elpy codebase in the GitHub repository finds almost nothing about "autodoc".

Comment: There is [autodoc.el](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-helm/blob/master/developer-tools/autodoc.el). Or, the built in `eldoc-mode`.

Comment: @scribe autodoc.el is for elisp functions, according to its docs – not sure why that would be relevant for Python? Ditto for eldoc-mode.

Answer (score 0):

The *autotdoc* module referenced in the Elpy docs is a specific [Elpy module](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#option-elpy-modules). You can enable it by [configuring Elpy](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#configuration). You can find its definition in Elpy's main source file [`elpy.el`](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/blob/840713f23af99b83d04034c3703f7e73c3baa7dc/elpy.el#L3821)